# Backup Office 365 sharepoint site? (company.sharepoint.com)

Tags: backup, office-365

Is it possible to synchronize or backup an Office 365 SharePoint site?

The company I work for want to use Microsofts "cloud" SharePoint offering, but they wont go ahead if they can't back it up on premis or somewhere else another of our online servers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of now, there is no out of the box facility to backup an entire SharePoint site and restore it to another farm as you do for on premise SharePoint applications.

The only option currently available would be to use the "Save site as template" option for sites, which would take a backup of max 50 MB. Visit [this blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/lystavlen/archive/2011/10/10/how-to-back-up-office-365-sharepoint-online-data.aspx) for more details.

You can check out for third party solutions, which comes with a pricing. One among them is [MetaVis SavePoint](http://www.metavistech.com/content/metavis-announces-office-365-sharepoint-backup-and-archiving-tool) which might be what you are looking for.

Good Luck .

Comment: Thanks. That MetaVis link could be something. will investigate further.

Comment: There are a lot of third party tools. AvePoint has a good one for syncing between on-premise and cloud. http://www.avepoint.com/sharepoint-online-migration-docave/

Comment: Another option you might consider is a service we just launched: http://www.leaphq.com/backup walkthrough here:
http://community.zevenseas.com/Blogs/Daniel/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=151

Comment: That's simply perfect Daniel. Great Tool !!!

Answer (score 1):

Activate daily backups for all selected users with office 365 domain. Backup for office 365 you gain all emails, daily automated backups and more. Easily export user data for local archive to recover without overwriting existing information data.

http://www.cloudally.com/Blog/2013/03/12/office-365-do-we-need-to-backup-our-own-data/